# Message app doesn't merge messages sent/received from same number but different format

Tags: contacts, sms

My network provider usually sends incoming SMSs with number format like +84123456 (equivalent to 0123456), but sometimes 0123456, and I usually save in my contact, and send SMS to 0123456.

In my old Android phones running 2.3 and 3.0, the Message app can regconize and merge them into 1 thread. But with my new Android running on 4.0.1, they are seperated into 2 threads, 1 for +84123456, and 1 for 0123456.

Can I make it merge them?

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: FPT F9, a local one in my country.